# Isomorphism between $\mathbb Z$ and $(0,\infty)\cap\mathbb Q$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am trying to improve my understanding of Isomorphisms between groups. I can prove most cases when asked to however I can't solve the following question.

Are the groups $\mathbb Z$ and $(0, \infty)$ $\cap$ $\mathbb Q$ where the latter is thought of as a group under multiplication?

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: If you had to guess, with a gun to your head, would you guess that they were isomorphic or that they were not? And what makes you answer in the way that you do?

Comment: Call $G=(0,\infty)\cap\mathbb{Q}$ to type less. Let $a\in G$ be the image of $1$. Then the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ is just $a^{n}$, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $a=r/s$ with $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $gcd(r,s)=1$, then if $p$ is a prime  larger than $r$ and $s$ we will never have $p=a^n$.